# Product Attribute Filters All Returning 0 Products In Layered Navigation After Magmi Import

Tags: attributes, import, layered-navigation, magmi, multiple-select-layered

I have recently used Magmi to import all of my product data. The data imports fine and is visible in the frontend, however the layered navigation does not mirror the product data that is visible inside the admin. The attributes that are not working are multiselect and select product attributes.

I have tried reindexing all indexes multiple times and clearing all caches but it doesnt seem to have any effect. It seems as though if I view the product inside the admin and save it with changes to the filterable attribute, then the layered navigation appears reflecting these changes. Magento seems to ignore any data imported from Magmi.

Does anyone know how to ensure the layered navigation reflects the product data stored in the database?

Comment: Is this Magento1 or magento 2?

Comment: This is Magento 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the reason for this not working was that the client had converted a dropdown product attribute to a multiselect via the database and not removed the original values for each product.

As a dropdown attribute Magento stores the values inside the catalog_product_entity_int and as a multiselect attribute stores values inside the catalog_product_entity_varchar. If the values aren't removed from the catalog_product_entity_int table then Magento ignores the values inside the catalog_product_entity_varchar table hence why the fitered navigation wasn't working.